# Find the distribution law of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $X$ be a random variable with an exponential distribution $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$, such that its expected value $\mathbb E[X] = 2$.
>
> Let $f$ be a function such that:
>
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\lceil x\rceil,& x\in[0,3)\\ 6,& x\geqslant 3\end{cases}$$
>
> Determine the distribution law for the random variable $Y=f(X).$

The first thing I did was determine $\lambda$ to be $1/2$. Then I set up the probability density function of the random variable $X$ and got confused when I realized $f(X)$ is neither invertible nor strictly monotonic.

I assume there is a more intuitive and obvious approach that I'm missing. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

On base of $X>0$ a.s. and the definition of $f$ it can be concluded that $Y=f(X)$ will take values in $\{1,2,3,6\}$ a.s..

So to be found are:

- $P(Y=1)=P(X\in(0,1])$
- $P(Y=2)=P(X\in(1,2])$
- $P(Y=3)=P(X\in(2,3))$
- $P(Y=6)=P(X\in[3,\infty))$

Comment: Minor error: $P(Y=3) = P(X\in (2,3))$ (open interval).

Comment: @AlexR Thank you! Repaired.

Comment: Glad to help. You are welcome.